# Sqlite - Will Insert operations block the reading?

Tags: multithreading, performance, sqlite, locking, blocking

My sqlite db is simple: one table, two columns. One column is the url of an image, another column is the bytes of the image.

I then have two threads.

One thread (*writing thread*) is downloading a very large image (let's say 5MB). And when the image is downloaded, the thread insert the url & the bytes of the image into the db.

Another thread (*reading thread*) is randomly query for an image, every 1 sec in a loop.

My question is:

**Will the "writing thread" block the "reading thread" sometimes?**

I have set `PRAGMA locking_mode=NORMAL`;

I have this question because I suffers the blocking and thought if I set locking_mode to NORMAL, the blocking shouldn't be there.

I mean, I wish it could be like this: I have a background thread is just handling the writing at very lowest priority. Then even if the insert costs much time, say 10 secs, the reading thread won't be affected.

Is there any way to do this? or what I am missing?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/wal.html)

Comment: I have used PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL. It is the same. When the database gets big, say, 5G, every insert may cost 2 - 10 secs, and the reading thread then is blocked, and hang there

Comment: Are you using the same db connection for all threads? If so you will block; you must use separate calls to sqlite3_open in each thread.